# Assimp.Net GetTextureCoords missing from Assimp.Mesh

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opentk, assimp

I'm facing a very strange error in my VS2010 project that uses c# + OpenTK + Assimp.net (The packages of the last 2 are from NuGet, so I suppose them updated to their latest version)

When I try to iterate the vector3 of the UV coordinates using:

```
model.Meshes[n].GetTextureCoords(0)[i]
```

I get the following error:

> error CS1061: 'Assimp.Mesh' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetTextureCoords' and no extension method 'GetTextureCoords'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Assimp.Mesh' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't understand why! Can someone please help me?

AssimpNet is correctly referenced (I'm able to load and visualize any 3D model correctly if I comment the UV part)

And in the using part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;                //Required by Assimp-net
using System.Reflection;        //Required by Assimp-net
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Platform;

using Assimp;                   //Required by Assimp-net
using Assimp.Configs;           //Required by Assimp-net
```

EDIT: I also tried to change the order of the "using"s... or to remove some of them to see if there was some sort of namespace clashing but without any success

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `Mesh.TextureCoordinateChannels[0][i]`. `GetTextureCoords()` does not exist. If you saw it anywhere in a tutorial, let me know where.